# Grails 2.2.2 'stop-app' calls Hsqldb's 'shutdown' sql command

Tags: grails, hsqldb

I am running `hsqldb 2.2.9` in server mode (separate jvm from grails), every time grails `stop-app` calls hsql's `shutdown` sql command.

Can I prevent this behavior? I hope `hsqdb`keep running every `run-app/stop-app`.

When I call stop-app, hsqldb server responses:

```
[Server@4a13ccea]: [Thread[HSQLDB Server @4a13ccea,5,main]]: handleConnection(Socket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=63260,localport=9001]) entered
[Server@4a13ccea]: [Thread[HSQLDB Server @4a13ccea,5,main]]: handleConnection() exited
[Server@4a13ccea]: [Thread[HSQLDB Connection @afe1bc5,5,HSQLDB Connections @4a13ccea]]: 3:Trying toconnect user 'SA' to DB (glitter)
[Server@4a13ccea]: [Thread[HSQLDB Connection @afe1bc5,5,HSQLDB Connections @4a13ccea]]: 3:Connecteduser 'SA'
[Server@4a13ccea]: 3:HSQLCLI:GETSESSIONATTR
[Server@4a13ccea]: 3:HSQLCLI:GETSESSIONATTR
[Server@4a13ccea]: 3:SHUTDOWN
```

Sorry for my poor english..

Regards,
Keiji

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to find a solution in Grails to avoid sending the SHUTDOWN command to the database.

But you can keep the HSQLDB Server alive with the `server.remote_open=true` property and use a connection property that opens the database if it has been shutdown by Grails.

http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/listeners-chapt.html#lsc_remote_open

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're terminating the process, so yes it will stop hsqldb...

You could also run a separate Hsqldb instance with the appropriate JDBC url set http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch01.html

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is specific code in Grails to call SHUTDOWN only when it uses HSQL.
See https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-2687

Unfortunately they don't check if it is an in-process server or not.